# how to transform a space to optimally separate data

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not a mathematician, but I need mathematical help. Apologies in advance for notational anomolies and/or poor tagging :-)

I have a classification problem where data points $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ fall into one of two classes: $A$ or $B$. I am interested only in the distance $d(x)$ from the origin to any point $x$ because I believe it will be sufficient to classify any point $x$ into its correct class - the coordinate origin has been translated to at (or near) the mean of the data points in $A$.

I propose to define $d(x) = \sqrt{x^TMx}$ for some positive-definite matrix $M$ and want to know how to find the matrix $M$ that will "optimally" separate my data. If someone has a useful definition of "optimal separation", I would like to hear it :-) Failing that, I would suggest defining $$A_{max} = \max_{x \in A}  d(x)$$ and $$B_{min} = \min_{x \in B}  d(x)$$ and then maximising the ratio $B_{min}/A_{max}$.

What is clear to me is that using an identity matrix (Euclidian distance) or inverted covariance matrix of points in $A$ (Mahalanobis distance) do not "optimally" separate the data by this definition.

Comment: A more common approach to classification problems (see [linear support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Linear_SVM)) is to find an optimal separating *hyperplane* rather than an ellipsoid; that is, find the unit vector $u$ which maximizes $\min\limits_{x\in B} u^Tx - \max\limits_{x\in A}u^Tx$. Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to try this?

Comment: My data is not linearly separable. To contrive a kernel-based transformation of the space that would be linearly separable seems likely to be completely unintuitive and beyond the capability of users of the system I'm developing. So I'm seeking an alternative to SVMs. It occurred to me that if this question has an answer, I might have the basis for finding a viable alternative in my context.

Comment: How about the fixed transformation to a $n(n+1)/2$-dimensional space of quadratic terms, $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1^2,2x_1x_2,\ldots,2x_1x_n,\ x_2^2,\ldots,2x_2x_n,\ \ldots,\ x_n^2)$? Now $d(x)^2=\sum m_{ii} x_i^2+2\sum m_{ij}x_ix_j$ is linear in this space, so you can do linear SVM here and your users don't have to contrive any kernels themselves. The only thing is that this maximizes $\min\limits_{x\in B} d^2(x)-\max\limits_{x\in A} d^2(x)$ subject to $\lVert M\rVert_F=1$ instead of your proposed criterion.

Comment: Interesting - thanks :-)